# c++ networking issue- my OS does not send ack

Tags: c++, networking

I wrote an application in c++ which send data over tcp connection to several machines.as part of the protocol I use in my application, the other side sends hearbeat messages from time to time, then I know that the connection is still alive.
now, I want this application to work on 100 machines or more at the same time. but, I see that sometimes I don't get these heartbeat messages although they sent: I see in wireshark that the packet arrived, then my OS doesn't ack on this message, so there are some retransmit without any ack from my OS. if I look in the window size property - I saw that there is no issue in this part. what can be the root cause for this behavior? it is something in my code that I should change? 
this is my select code:

```
while(it != sockets.end() ){
        FD_SET((*it), &readFds);
        if( (int)(*it) > fdCount ){
            fdCount = *it;
        }
        it++;
    }



int res = select(fdCount, &readFds, NULL, NULL, NULL );



   I'm using server 2008 r2.
```

I don't see any stress on the network card or on the switch.
Please help me!

thanks

Comment: Would you mind showing us how you populate and use the `readFds`? Also, just so you know, Windows ignores first argument of `select()`.